# How do I store my default padding in Theme.of() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, padding, flutter-theme

As far as I understand I'm supposed to access my style constants in flutter via Theme.of(). In Android I would have stored them in `dimens.xml`. None of the entries in ThemeData look to me like they are about padding amounts and it also seems impossible to add new ones. Where should I store the my constants for padding amounts?

Answer (score 3):

Create a contants.dart file and store the default padding there

```
const kDefaultPadding = EdgeInsets.all(16);
```

Comment: While this seems to be a possible way to do that, it seems strange to me to do that instead of Theme.of(). Is this somewhere recommended as best practice?

Comment: Theme.of() is all about colors and font styles. Apart from the constant example above, another way you can do this is you can create a base Widget class which defines default padding values and then all your Widgets inherit from this base Widget - but that might be an overkill.

Comment: Has kDefaultPadding been deprecated? I ask because I can't find it in the documentation on api.flutter.dev

For example I can find kControlChannelName on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ChannelBuffers/kControlChannelName-constant.html

But no constants for Padding on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html

Where can I find out more about it?

Comment: @Dan1ell "kDefaultPadding" is user-defined here (and the "k" prefix is just a naming convention for constants). It does nothing in isolation, but you can plug it in wherever an EdgeInsets is expected.

Comment: With this approach, you cannot encapsulate your UI in a separate package. For example I am making two apps that use some common UI elements, but they differ in color, text fonts, paddings, etc. With `Theme.of()` we can handle colors and text fonts, but not global numerical constants like "padding".

Answer (score 3):

I made a util function to keep paddings etc consistent

```
const kDefaultSpacingFactor = 8;
// this function will simple take a value and multiply with the constant scaling
// factor, to keep paddings etc consistent
double spacingFactor(double multiplier) {
  return multiplier * kDefaultSpacingFactor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access sizing using `Theme.of(context)` You can create a theme extension. It ends up being more boiler plate code than storing them as constants, but it reduces the need to import random constants into your code and it enables all the features that come with using themes.

Here's an example theme extension

```dart
class AppSizes extends ThemeExtension<AppSizes> {
  static const defaultSizes = AppSizes(16);

  final double padding;

  const AppSizes(this.padding);

  @override
  AppSizes copyWith({
    double? padding,
  }) {
    return AppSizes(padding ?? this.padding);
  }

  @override
  ThemeExtension<AppSizes> lerp(covariant ThemeExtension<AppSizes>? other, double t) {
    if (other is! AppSizes) {
      return this;
    }
    return AppSizes(lerpDouble(padding, other.padding, t)!);
  }
}
```

From there you'll need to include the extension in your MaterialApp

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
        extensions: [AppSizes.defaultSizes], // here
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorScheme: darkColorScheme,
        extensions: [AppSizes.defaultSizes], // here
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

And then you can access them like this

```dart
Theme.of(context).extension<AppSizes>()!.padding
```